# MPJ/MPIJava what is the state of java-MPI bindings?

Tags: java, ssh, mpi, daemon, mpj-express

I am working on my thesis and I need to run JVM-software on cluster computers. I have tried MPJ Express, but it seems buggy, and since I cannot use SSH between computers when I get a job, a lot of hacking is needed to make the software run. The process is not ideal.

I looked into MPIJava, however, I have had no luck compiling it and it seems too ancient to bother.

Recently I discovered fastmpj.com which seems to be very close to MPJ Express. This library also requires daemons to be started via SSH, so I get the same problems as with MPJ Express.

What is the state of art in java-MPI programming now? Are there any libraries or methods that will allow me to run a java-mpi program with the "mpirun" command without starting daemons at each node?

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Java bindings to MPI, of course, but the most recent distributions of OpenMPI are shipping with [Java bindings that cover MPI 1.2](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java), with work underway to include more recent developments.   It's not clear how extensively they have yet been tested, but then you can run it just with the usual mpiexec type commands.